# The Galois group of a specialized polynomial

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, function-fields

Let $P(t,x)\in\mathbb Q[t,x]$ be irreducible with Galois group $G$ over $\mathbb Q(t)$. It is known that if $t_0\in\mathbb Q$ is such that $P(t_0,x)$ is separable, then the Galois group of this specialized polynomial is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$. Is this true also if $P(t_0,x)$ is not separable? I haven't been able to find a proof  or a counterexample.

Comment: @TobErnack I think I am missing something in your comment. In characteristic zero the splitting field of any (univariate) polynomial is surely Galois. Separability is not an issue because you can remove any repeated factor without affecting the splitting field, right?

Comment: Can you give a source to the result about the effect of specialization on the Galois group?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen One reference is Lang's Algebra, chapter VII, section 2, theorem 2.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something a little misleading about the formulation of this question. Given such a polynomial $P(t,x)$, one has not only a Galois group $G$, but a natural action of $G$ on $d = \mathrm{deg}(P)$ points well defined up to conjugation. Given a separable specialization $P(t_0,x)$, it is true that the Galois group $H$ of this specialization is isomorphic (abstractly) to a subgroup of $G$, but it is *also* true that there is an inclusion $H \rightarrow G$ such that the action of $H$ on the $d$ roots of $P(t_0,x)$ is the restriction of the given permutation representation of $G$. When $P(t_0,x)$ is not separable, the Galois group $H$ no longer has any obvious action on $d$ points, and so one must settle for your weaker formulation that there merely exists an  abstract inclusion from $H$ to $G$.

Still, the answer to this weaker formulation is still no. The easiest way to construct a counterexample is to consider isotrivial covers. Let $K/\mathbf{Q}$ be any field of degree $d$ with Galois group $G$. Let $\theta \in K$ be a primitive element. Let $\alpha \in K$ be any element at all. Now consider the minimal polynomial of $t \theta + \alpha$ over $\mathbf{Q}(t)$. This will define a degree $d$ polynomial $P(t,x)$. For a generic specialization $t = t_0 \in \mathbf{Q}$, the element $t_0 \theta + \alpha \in K$ will also be a primitive root, and so the Galois group will be $G$. But the specialization at $t = 0$ will have $\alpha$ as a root. In fact, the corresponding polynomial will be a power of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. So your claim is now the following: if $H$ is the Galois group of the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. But this is absurd --- by Galois theory, $H$ is transparently a *quotient* of $G$. So it suffices to consider an example of a pair $(G,H)$ with $H$ a quotient of $G$ so that $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$. This doesn't happen for groups $G$ of extremely low order which perhaps indicate why you failed to find a counterexample. Perhaps the easiest example is $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_3)$, which acts faithfully on $8$ points, and is a central extension of $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{F}_3) = S_4$. If $S_4$ was a subgroup of $G$, it would have to be normal, but then $S_4$ has no automorphisms, so since $Z(S_4)$ is trivial this would force $G$ to be $S_4 \times \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$, which it is not. Thus the answer is no.

You can also easily write down an explicit example if you like. First write down a $G$-extension (say coming from the $y$-coordinate of the $3$-torsion of the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$)

$$K = \mathbf{Q}[\theta]/(961 - 558\theta^4 - 216 \theta^6 - 27 \theta^8),$$

which has Galois closure with Galois group $G = \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{F}_3)$, 
and then let $\alpha = \theta^2$, whose Galois closure has Galois group $S_4$. Then let $P(t,x)$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha + t \theta$, which is:

$$923521 - 536238*t^4 - 207576*t^6 - 25947*t^8 - 2144952*t^2*x - 1245456*t^4*x -
 207576*t^6*x - 1072476*x^2 - 1868184*t^2*x^2 - 518940*t^4*x^2 - 415152*x^3 -
 415152*t^2*x^3 + 259470*x^4 + 120528*t^2*x^4 + 15066*t^4*x^4 + 241056*x^5 +
 60264*t^2*x^5 + 76788*x^6 + 5832*t^2*x^6 + 11664*x^7 + 729*x^8$$

Then $P(t,x)$ has Galois group $G$ but $P(0,x) = (27x^4 + 216x^3 + 558x^2 - 961)^2$ has Galois group $S_4$.

Comment: in the above explanation,  can the Galois group H of this specialization is isomorphic to G?